# Control a MOXA IOLogik wia TCP

Tags: microcontroller

I know this is strictly not an electrical engineering problem, but I think it's where it has a best chance of being answered.

I'm using a [MOXA IOLogik](http://www.moxa.com/product/iologik-e2210.htm) (it's a Ethernet Micro RTU Controller) to monitor and control some security systems with digital IO and I want to modify a IOLokig internal register via TCP to send some commands to the controller from a server.

Anyone knows how to do this? how should the structure of the TCP message be?

UPDATE: It uses the modbus protocol for communication.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @MattYoung it's a ethernet RTU controller. I added a link to the official page

Comment: For starters, have a look at [MODBUS MESSAGING ON TCP/IP IMPLEMENTATION GUIDE](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf) and [MODBUS APPLICATION PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf). These documents come from www.modbus.org where you can go for further information and specifications. You might also have a look at [INTRODUCTION TO MODBUS TCP/IP](http://www.prosoft-technology.com/kb/assets/intro_modbustcp.pdf) from Acromag.

Answer (score 1):

I put up a basic implementation of a ModbusTCP interface at http://pastebin.com/5twF0gUb
This is a C# class that you should mostly be able to plug into an application. I stripped it out of some other code and tried to massage it into a generic format but you may need to tweak it a bit. I glanced at the manual for that controller and it has all the addresses listed that you should need.